# Add total to a table in layout?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, table, layouts

[image]

How can I add a total (sum) at the bottom of this table? I would like to sum the vines and Acerage columns. Using Arcmap.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE.  Please [edit] the question to specify the software you are using (including version), and the format of the data in question.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that you're using ArcMap. The attribute table is not Excel.  It doesn't have the ability to summarise data.  You could do one of the following:

1. Manually create another row or text element and populate the data.
2. Export the data to Excel and run the sums there.  Then copy and paste the table back into ArcMap.

Comment: Thank you! The second option seems most appropriate for my project.

By Copy and Paste, you mean import the table from excel as an image? Can you specify.

Comment: @SlyWhiteSheep in Excel select your table and Ctrl+C to copy, in ArcMap layout Ctrl+V to paste.  Alternatively you can Insert > Object > Excel Worksheet which keeps the link to the Excel table (if you want to modify later)

Answer (score 0):

You could also export the attribute table to a .dbase file and **then click** **and drag** that file into Excel. If you try to use open sometimes it doesn't work.