# Display coordinates with page change in Data Driven Pages in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layouts, data-driven-pages, dynamic-tables

I want to insert X,Y coordinates in a layout as a separate table in ArcMap
every time I change pages by using Data Driven Pages the X,Y coordinates ​​values changed.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Questions here need to have a question, not just a question mark at the end of a declarative sentence. Please [Edit] the question to give a better idea of your goal (and review the title I generated), and include what you have tried.

Comment: This is a way to go https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/170707/adding-labels-with-symbols-to-legend-in-arcmap/170763#170763 unless you have 'production something' extension.

Comment: See also https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/185577/center-text-in-table-column/185583#185583

Comment: Do you really need a table for 2 fields? You could insert data driven attribute fields for X and Y, format the fields so they look like one table.